# DOJO dialog box not opening second time

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, dojo

I am using DOJO for a dialog box called 'Edit'. Clicking on the 'Edit' button the first time opens a dialog. When closing the dialog using the 'x' button on the right of the dialog screen, the dialog disappears. It works first time. But the subsequent clicks on 'Edit' button after that don't work and the dialog is not populated. I want those to work as well. Refreshing the page makes everything OK.

```
<div style="float: right;">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${fn:startsWith(user.languageLocale, 'fr')}">
        <c:set var="a" value="75px"/></c:when>
        <c:otherwise><c:set var="a" value="60px"/></c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

    <c:if test="${not formDisabled}">
    <a
        id="Pane"
        dojoType="Popup"
        popupCloseTitle="<spring:message code='close'/>"
        popupTitle="<spring:message code='edit'/>"
        href="/.../.../Disc.htm"
        destroyOnClose="true"
        popupWidth="920px"
        buttonWidth="<c:out value="${a}"/>"
        zIndex="30"
        buttonText="<spring:message code='edit'/>"
    </a>
    </c:if>

    <input type="hidden" id="Data" value="${Data }"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `Popup` defined? It does not seem to be a standard Dojo dijit.

Answer (score 1):

Having no experience with the `rmt.NewModalPopupButton` widget, I would suspect the issue is the `destroyOnClose="true"` attribute being set.  From the sound of that attribute I wouldn't be surprised if the actual dialog widget is being destroyed and therefore can't be re-shown on subsequent events.

Comment: I meddled with destroyOnClose values setting it to true and removing it. But that doesn't seem to work. Clueless on what todo